# How can remove one row in table with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html-table, row

In this partial view I fill a table with a model an `foreach` loop, like below:

```
<table id="tblGroup" class="table table-bordered">

<thead style="background: #eeeeee;">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;">ردیف</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">نام</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">تخصص</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">سابقه</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">حذف</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody  style="text-align: center;">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" id="groupId"/>



        <tr id="idrow">


            <td >@(orderCounter++)</td>
            <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Name @blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Family</td>
            <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Specially</td>
            <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).WorkYear</td>
            <td><a href="#"  id ="linkdelete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>

        </tr>


}
      </tbody>
```

I want to remove one row when the remove link is clicked.
This is my JQuery, but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#linkdelete").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/DeleteGroup",
        data: { id: $('input#groupId').val() },
        //cache: false,
        //contentType: false,
        //processData: false,
        //mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                $("#idrow").remove();
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("خطا!");
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (in the <input>`,  `<tr>` and `<a>` elements). Replace them with class names and get the associated row using `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

Comment: @stephen $(this) will not be accessible in ajax success, we first need to store $(this) into one variable before ajax  and the  we can access $(this) using that variable

Answer (score 0):

add data-id attribute to anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" data-id="@item.Id" id ="linkdelete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

You can delete row like this:

```
$("#linkdelete").click(function (e) {
    var obj = $(this); // first store $(this) in obj
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // get id of data using this 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/DeleteGroup",
        data: { id: id },
        //cache: false,
        //contentType: false,
        //processData: false,
        //mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                $(obj).closest("tr").remove(); // You can remove row like this
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("خطا!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('input#groupId').val()` will return the value of the first input :)

Comment: how can i return the value of row that i select??

Comment: @shayantalaei, You need to use class names and relative selectors (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html)

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to have class as a click event selector in the place of id inorder to achieve respective rows delete..
I have modified your code to achieve that..

HTML:

```
 <table id="tblGroup" class="table table-bordered">

 <thead style="background: #eeeeee;">
 <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">ردیف</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">نام</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">تخصص</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">سابقه</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">حذف</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody  style="text-align: center;">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" id="groupId"/>



    <tr id="idrow">

        <td >@(orderCounter++)</td>
        <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Name    
        <td> @blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Family</td>
        <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).Specially</td>
        <td>@blSpecialist.Find(item.Sp_id).WorkYear</td>
        <td><a href="#"  class ="linkdelete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>     </td>

    </tr>


  }
  </tbody>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(".linkdelete").click(function (e) {


$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/DeleteGroup",
    data: { id: $('input#groupId').val() },
    //cache: false,
    //contentType: false,
    //processData: false,
    //mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "Json",
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // You can remove row like this
        }
        eval(result.Script);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("خطا!");
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shayan jan you can do this : 
 - use `class` insted of `id` for anchor link (id is a unique selector).
Working example with hard coded rows : https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/128/

```
$("#tblGroup").on("click" , ".linkdelete" ,(function () {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var id = tr.prev().val();


  alert("id: " + id);
  //remove below line in your code it is just for example
  tr.remove();
  data = { id: id };
  console.log("data =>" , data);
  $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/DeleteGroup",
        data: data ,
        //cache: false,
        //contentType: false,
        //processData: false,
        //mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                tr.remove(); // You can remove row like this
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("خطا!");
        }
    });
  });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

1.use class insted of id for anchor link.

2. use .on() method instead of .click() method, and put your code inside the  $(document).ready() event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body')on('click', '.linkdelete', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Admin/DeleteGroup",
      data: { id: $('input#groupId').val() },
      //cache: false,
      //contentType: false,
      //processData: false,
      //mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
      type: "Post",
      dataType: "Json",
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.Success) {
          $("#idrow").remove();
        }
        eval(result.Script);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("خطا!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```